# Microsoft Graph API - 503 Service Unavailable with "UnknownError"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Our application performs lots of calls to MS Graph API, mainly calls to messages, calendars and contacts. Due to huge amount of calls we experience throttling and sometime 503 Service Unavailable error. Sometimes description of 503 Service Unavailable error is following:

*ErrorCode: "UnknownError", ErrorMessage: ""*

Usually those errors disappear after one or several retries.

Starting on 5th of November the amount of such *"UnknownError"* errors increased dramatically. I couldn't find any MS Graph API service update description that could lead to those changes. What is a cause for the increase of those errors? How can I examine it?

Answer (score 2):

Having the same issue, and it's obviously not related to the throttling like [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58961372) suggested.
The sorting seems to be causing the issue for some reason. Almost as if there was a bad message that the API was failing to parse & throwing the exception.

Here is a full trace:

```
➜  workturbo curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages\?%24select=changeKey\&%24filter=isDraft+eq+false+and+lastModifiedDateTime+lt+2020-02-01T23%3A19%3A57Z\&%24orderby=lastModifiedDateTime+desc\&%24skip=0\&%24top=5
*   Trying 20.190.132.119...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to graph.microsoft.com (20.190.132.119) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=graph.microsoft.com
*  start date: Jul  1 21:55:17 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Jul  1 21:55:17 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "graph.microsoft.com" matched cert's "graph.microsoft.com"
*  issuer: C=US; ST=Washington; L=Redmond; O=Microsoft Corporation; OU=Microsoft IT; CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /beta/me/messages?%24select=changeKey&%24filter=isDraft+eq+false+and+lastModifiedDateTime+lt+2020-02-01T23%3A19%3A57Z&%24orderby=lastModifiedDateTime+desc&%24skip=0&%24top=5 HTTP/1.1
> Host: graph.microsoft.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer <OBFUSCATED>
>
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: application/json
< request-id: 3903e2c4-325b-4925-8544-20383e2a2944
< client-request-id: 3903e2c4-325b-4925-8544-20383e2a2944
< x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West US","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"003","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_17"}}
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< Date: Tue, 21 Jul 2020 19:30:23 GMT
< Content-Length: 198
<
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-07-21T19:30:23",
      "request-id": "3903e2c4-325b-4925-8544-20383e2a2944"
    }
  }
* Connection #0 to host graph.microsoft.com left intact
}* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: as a work around I figured that by removing the isDraft filter it worked. But this is definitely an issue on their side... I wished they were actually looking into the SO issues...

Answer (score 1):

Please take a read of our guidance on Throttling. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling

You need to respect the retry-after header that gets returned with calls. Otherwise you'll get 429s and sometimes 503s like you are getting.

If you are using our Microsoft Graph SDKs, it has a built in throttling handler.

Comment: Thank you @Jeremy. I figured out that those errors were indeed throttling related issues. I wasn't expecting 503s error though.

Comment: Great, would you mind marking this as the answer please? thanks.

Comment: I'm getting 503s but no preceding 429s, and the 503 response headers don't contain Retry-After.

Comment: Havent seen so bad api as Microsofts API one for 10years.. not working documented features, 30 months old major issues, random 503 WITHOUT any retry-after header..

Is this community - developed API, or paid from Microsoft to employees? 

ITs time to migrate from.